# Android : NeighboringCellInfo

Tags: android, telephony, signal-strength

NeighboringCellInfo() on Android API, I want to know this function return all neighbor cell?
And one of result is current cell which our device connected?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should.

But I never found a device where it did. Please report back here if you find any GSM device with any Android OS Version that does report at least one neighboring cell. Thank you!

You should be able to use the following code to get them:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
List<NeighboringCellInfo> neighbours = tm.getNeighboringCellInfo();
```

You need the following permission in your AndroidManidfest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_UPDATES"/>
```

Since I never saw any result in the list I do not know whether the currently connected cell is included. I would guess it is not.

Comment: Motorola Charm return the neighboring cell information. try it.

Comment: @Anieeh Thanks! I cannot order it via Amazon anymore. It seems to be discontinued :-(

Comment: Thanks for your help.And I want to know when I call neighboringCellInfo(), I always got "Lac = -1 , Cid = -1 , Rssi = 31" Why?. Thanks again

Comment: Maybe for the same reason it doesn't have any entries for me? Maybe this is simply not impplemented correctly on your phone?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.. As seen @ [d.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo.html) ;)

[Here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/telephony/java/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo.java) you have even source to take a deeper look..

Cheers

Comment: Thanks,I want to know when I call neighboringCellInfo(), I always got "Lac = -1 , Cid = -1 , Rssi = 31" Why?. Thanks again.