# What does the "Neighboring cell" mean in the class of "NeighboringCellInfo"?

Tags: android

I know that using the class "NeighboringCellInfo" in android programming, returns the parameters(details) associated with the Neighboring cell as mentioned in the android docs.

I would like to know, if it returns the details of the neighboring cell of the same Mobile operator or can it return the details of the neighbouring cell irrespective of its mobile operator, the cell belongs to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android : NeighboringCellInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715503/android-neighboringcellinfo)

Answer (score 0):

As njzk2 said, the response is in the other question.

But yes, it should return the info of the neighbor cell. But I've tried myself, and discovered that the list obtained in telephonymanager.getallcellinfo() was not empty, but was very difficult to handle.